# Android - OneBusAway: translate message for succesfully sent problems

Tags: java, android

I need trying to change/translate the message shown in the OneBusAway Android app after sending with success a report about an arrival time or a bus stop.

The dialog shows the message "Your issue has been successfully reported", plus an "Ok" button:

[image]

The message shown does not depend on the language of the operating system. I looked in the whole code for that string, and for substrings, without beeing able to find anything.

More, debugging step-by-step it seems the dialog is originated from some Android library.

Any idea on how to approach the problem in order to change and/or translate the message?

Comment: find view by it's id of given.

Comment: May you please explain better?

There is no layout or fragment ora activity in the code which belongs to that dialog, I looked for it and was not able to find it.

Comment: from Which library it's come ?

Comment: I don't know: this was my question. 

I was not able to track the dialog, nor I was able to find where is istantiated in the code. I performed a step-by-step debug and the dialog seems to be originated in some system library, but I may be wrong.